# Recognize when is the app first launched WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Does anybody know how can I recognize when is the app first launched? I need to show message dialog only at the first start after install. Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `IsolatedStorageSettings` and check for a flag.

```cs
  var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
  if (!settings.Contains("WasLaunched")) {
    MessageBox.Show("First time to launch");
    settings.Add("WasLaunched", true);
  }
```

Note that re-deploying your app will reset the flag since its just a file saved in Isolated Storage but this should work if you launch your app from within emulator/actual device.

Comment: Will files in Isolated Storage will be deleted when user will update application?

Comment: No. If an update is carried out through Market Place it performs an update rather than uninstall/install as the case with Visual Studio deploy.